# right menu sticks to bottom of main div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I created 3 divs, one for the **left-menu** (displaying chapters to jump to)
one for the **main article** displaying images, and one for the **right-menu** (displaying small paragraphs)
my problem is, the **right-menu** would stick to the bottom of the main div, instead of sticking to the main menu's right side.

Can anybody help ?

```css
.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #536162;
  height: 100vh;
  border-right: 2px solid #424642;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #b1aea2;
}

.menu-right {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #536162;
  border-left: 2px solid #424642;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow:auto">
  <div class="menu">
    <p class="menu-item">Chapter 1</p>
    <p class="menu-item">Chapter 2</p>
    <p class="menu-item">Chapter 3</p>
    <p class="menu-item">Chapter 4</p>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
    <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
    <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
    <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
    <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
    <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="menu-right">
    <p class="menu-item">Info 1</p>
    <p class="menu-item">Info 2</p>
    <p class="menu-item">Info 3</p>
    <p class="menu-item">Info 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly where `display:grid` is good for! Personally I avoid using `float` if I can.

If you change the first div (the one that wraps all other) to something like this: `<div class="wrapper" style="overflow:auto">` and add the following css it should work.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 20%;
  align-items: start; /* Only if you want the columns not being 100% height. */
}

.menu {
    background-color: #536162;
    height: 100vh;
    border-right: 2px solid #424642;
}
.main {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #b1aea2;
}
.menu-right {
    background-color: #536162;
    border-left: 2px solid #424642;
    position: relative;
}
```

If you want to know more about it, here is a nice article/website: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set its float to right. you set it to left. that's why it stuck to the left.

Second An important thing you must understand is that every pixel is calculated. even the borders are calculated when you add them to the width, so you must ensure that you calculate them right.

here I reset the CSS and set menu-right float to right then commented your borders and padding then it stuck to the right where you want it.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #536162;
  height: 100vh;
  /* border-right: 2px solid #424642; */
}
.main {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  /* padding: 15px; */
  background-color: #b1aea2;
}
.menu-right {
  float: right;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #536162;
  /* border-left: 2px solid #424642; */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <div style="overflow:auto">
        <div class="menu">
            <p class="menu-item">Chapter 1</p>
            <p class="menu-item">Chapter 2</p>
            <p class="menu-item">Chapter 3</p>
            <p class="menu-item">Chapter 4</p>
        </div>
    
        <div class="main">
            <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
            <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
            <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
            <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
            <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
            <img id="img" class="imgs" src="daisy.jpg">
        </div>
                
        <div class="menu-right">
            <p class="menu-item">Info 1</p>
            <p class="menu-item">Info 2</p>
            <p class="menu-item">Info 3</p>
            <p class="menu-item">Info 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hope my answer helps you.